# How to automatically deploy `.dmg` files to Apple Store via Azure Devops

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, azure-devops

In order to deploy iOS apps (apps for iPhone or iPad) to the Apple App store, I use the [Apple App Store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store) task.
This works, but this task only support deploying `.ipa` files (for iOS).

I also have a MacOS desktop application (a `.dmg` file).  How can this automatically be deployed from an Azure DevOps pipeline? The Apple App store task (that supports `.ipa`) does not seem to support `.dmg`, and I cannot find any documentation on it either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Apple App Store only support IPA file: Binary Path (File path, Required) - Path to the IPA file you want to publish to the specified track. A glob pattern can be used but it must resolve to exactly one IPA file. Currently, there is no option to achieve this.

A dmg file extension is used for default disk image format in Mac OS X (macOS) that replaced the older IMG format. It is used much like ISO images on Windows platform.
Files with dmg file extension can also be found as binary dumps created by Oracle programs. Should not be confused with the common Mac OS X (macOS) disk image that also shares the DMG extension.

An ipa file extension is generally used for application packages downloaded from Apple iTunes app store. The IPA is a container format that contains app installations.

Comment: do I understand it correctly that automatic `.dmg` deployment to Appe App Store is not supported by Azure Devops pipelines?

Comment: Yes. Currently this is not supported by Azure DevOps pipelines.